# removing a sequence of backslash and a frontslash in R

Tags: json, r, string

I have an object which is of the following type

```
{"url" : "http:\/\/sth.com", "url2" : "http:\/\/sth2.com" }
```

When this object is run as a parameter to an R function, I get an error

> Error: '/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting
>   ""http:/"

So I am thinking I may need to do some processing on the object.

However i am unable to test as in R I cannot assign `http:\/sth` as a string. - giving the same error.

Any idea how I can substitute the `\/` with just `/`?

---

It is a `JSON`; it is being generated from the twitter API. and being put into Active MQ. R is reading from it.
I cannot change the object , but I can apply some preprocessing on the above object before pushing to the queue

---

I tried the package `rjson' and`RJSONIO`, but the same error as shown above crops up; i am unable to perform the`fromJSON()` operation.

Comment: missing a couple of double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not having any problem. I copy/pasted your string into a file (call it `twit.txt`, I suppose that you got that kind of strings somewhere on a file) and then I run in R:

```
   require(RJSONIO)
   fromJSON(readLines("twit.txt"))
   #              url              url2 
   # "http://sth.com" "http://sth2.com"
```

So it seems that it parses the string correctly.